# Laravel class not found

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-4

I'm a Laravel newbie. I'm working with a package called Confide. It has an error which I'm trying to identify using the Log function. When I call the Log function I get an exception

```
Class 'Zizaco\Confide\Log' not found
```

when I include `use Illuminate\Log;`
I get an error message

```
Class 'Illuminate\Log' not found
```

What am I doing wrong? I have run `composer dump-auto -o` but there is no change

Here is a section of my code

```
<?php namespace Zizaco\Confide;

use Illuminate\Log;
use Illuminate\View\Environment;
use Illuminate\Config\Repository;
use InvalidArgumentException;
use Zizaco\Confide\ObjectProvider;



class Confide
{
```

and the code that causes an error is:

```
Log::info('The value is '.$token);
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You have to use just Log:

```
use Log;
```

Because this is not the class, but the Log Facade.

Answer (score 2):

It looks like `Illuminate\Log` is a namespace, not a class.

See the Laravel API here:
http://laravel.com/api/namespace-Illuminate.Log.html

Laravel uses [Monolog](https://github.com/seldaek/monolog), and creates a Log [facade](http://laravel.com/docs/facades) to it. You should be able to simply use `use Log;`.

Answer (score 1):

You can also try like this.

```
\Log::info('The value is '.$token);
```